# caching images served by servlet

Tags: java, http, image, servlets, caching

I'm serving up images from my servlet. The response content type is image/jpeg. I find that images requested from my servlet are not cached. How do I get them to be cached like file image requests normally are? I tried setting Cache-Control: public but to no avail.

Answer (score -10, accepted):

Ok.. looks like the default header fields should enable caching. I found a solution in another forum. Apparently, you need to explicitly set a content-length in the response. Wonder why though. I thought the HttpServletResponse would do that for us. Anyway, it worked like a charm and the image is getting cached nicely.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a link to the forum where you found the answer?

Answer (score 25):

The default servlet serving static content in containers like Tomcat doesn't set any cache control headers. You don't need write a servlet just for that. Just create a filter like this,

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request,
        ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) 
    throws IOException, ServletException {

    long expiry = new Date().getTime() + cacheAge*1000;

    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse)response;
    httpResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", expiry);
    httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age="+ cacheAge);

    chain.doFilter(request, response);

 }
```

Whenever you want add cache control, just add the filter to the resources in web.xml. For example,

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CacheControl</filter-name>
    <filter-class>filters.CacheControlFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CacheControl</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/images/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: The headers work in milliseconds, so `cacheAge` are the number of seconds you want stuff to be cached.

Comment: Can this filter used for css and javascript files too ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to send the [`ETag`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.19), [`Last-Modified`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.29) and [`Expires`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.21) headers along the response. The `ETag` represents the unique identifier of the file (usually composed based on a combination of filename, filesize and lastmodified timestamp). The `Last-Modified` represents the last modified timestamp of the file. The `Expires` header denotes how long the client is allowed to keep the file in cache. If the cache has been expired and the `ETag` or `Last-Modified` are available, then the client will send a `HEAD` request to check if the file needs to be renewed. If not, then the `Expires` will just be postponed again accordingly.

You can find here a servlet example which handles this all (and download resumes and automatic GZIP): [FileServlet supporting resume and GZIP](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/02/fileservlet-supporting-resume-and.html)

Answer (score 2):

For example, if you want to cache them for 1 month:

```
Calendar inOneMonth = Calendar.getInstance();
inOneMonth.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);

response.setDateHeader("Expires", inOneMonth.getTimeInMillis());
```

(this is in a `Filter` that handles the `*.jpg` pattern, for example)

But images should be cached by default - check your filters and configurations to see if something isn't setting the cache parameters incorrectly.