# Add expire cache for images in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, caching

I am trying to cache images on my jsp page.

I know that I can cache everything like this:

```
httpResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", System.currentTimeMillis() + 604800000L);
```

But I need to set expiration cache only for images. How can I do that? What is the easiest way?

Thanks

Comment: Very similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872613/caching-images-served-by-servlet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `servlet filter` which will listen for URLs that end in *.jpg, *.gif, *.png etc. and add the expires header in the response.

Comment: @boban0987 take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872613/caching-images-served-by-servlet