# Servlet response should be cached but isn't

Tags: java, caching, servlets, response

I am trying to cache the servlet response but somehow it is not working (Firebug is giving me 200 OK each time i refresh the page). This is the code I added in the servlet:

```
response.setContentType("application/javascript");
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setDateHeader("Last-Modified", 0);
response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=5184000");
response.setDateHeader("Expires", now + 5184000 * 1000);
response.addHeader("Vary", "Host");
```

I've also tried with `setHeader` and with `Last-Modified`, now.

Nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Thanks

This is how firebug shows me the response/request headers (when the resource should have been fetched from cache but isnt):

```
 Response Headersview source
 Cache-Control  max-age=5184000
 Connection Keep-Alive
 Content-Type   application/javascript;charset=UTF-8
 Date   Thu, 21 Mar 2013 09:53:48 GMT
 Expires    Sun, 31 Mar 2013 16:51:01 GMT
 Keep-Alive timeout=15, max=99



 Request Headersview source
 Accept */*
 Accept-Encoding    gzip, deflate
 Accept-Language    en-US,en;q=0.5
 Cache-Control  max-age=0
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872613/caching-images-served-by-servlet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `Last-Modified` requires cooperative coding in your servlet. When you send it to a client, that client will then send back, when requesting the same resource, one of a possible set of headers:

- If-Modified-Since:
- If-Unmodified-Since:

You would have to process these headers, determine if the content had changed since the given date and then send a 304 response if it hadn't. Lots of manual work. Also note that the `Last-Modified` date has to be [valid](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822) (e.g: `Tue, 15 Nov 1994 12:45:26 GMT`).

The simplest route for you would be to ignore `Last-Modified` for now, and instead use the `Cache-Control` and `Expires` headers. Your `Expires` header needs to be in a valid date format, as described for the `Last-Modified` header.

You can read up more on caching in general, in [this excellent document](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/).

Comment: thank you, removed the Last-Modified header and works like a charm!