# How to implement caching of images to speed up my web application

Tags: javascript, java

I want to speed up my web application which is in java and am also using ajax, javascript. can someone explain through an example to how to implement image caching.I am using IBM Webspere

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872613/caching-images-served-by-servlet

Comment: Isn't that usually done by the browsers? By default, every browser will cache the images, css, js files and you should not be worried about controlling those caching in server side..

Answer (score 0):

Ideally static content is cached by browser at client side but in order to reduce load on application server you can use HTTP server like Apache or IBM in between your client(browser, mobile ...) and  application server.
You can search  Use HTTP server to cache static content

Comment: That is what I want to know where can I put Expires and max-age for cahe-control of images. Please elucidate on this

Comment: Hi Abhi,                                                                                         Thumb rule for improving performance of system is to make system work on less data. although i had not used expires, max-age, cache control ... but keeping http server in between your application server and client will improve page loading time to much huge extent. i had seen it improves 40 to 70%